# How can multiple files be specified with "-files" in the CLI of Amazon for EMR?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-cli

I am trying to start an amazon cluster via the amazon CLI, but I am a little bit confused how I should specify multiple files. My current call is as follows:

```
aws emr create-cluster --steps Type=STREAMING,Name='Intra country development',ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[-files,s3://betaestimationtest/mapper.py,-
files,s3://betaestimationtest/reducer.py,-mapper,mapper.py,-reducer,reducer.py,-
input,s3://betaestimationtest/output_0_inter,-output,s3://betaestimationtest/output_1_intra] 
--ami-version 3.1.0 
--instance-groupsInstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m3.xlarge 
InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m3.xlarge --auto-terminate 
--log-uri s3://betaestimationtest/logs
```

However, Hadoop now complains that it cannot find the reducer file:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "reducer.py": error=2, No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? The file does exist in the folder I specify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For passing multiple files in a streaming step, you need to use file:// to pass the steps as a json file.

AWS CLI shorthand syntax uses comma as delimeter to separate a list of args. So when we try to pass in parameters like: "-files","s3://betaestimationtest/mapper.py,s3://betaestimationtest/reducer.py", then the shorthand syntax parser will treat mapper.py and reducer.py files as two parameters.

The workaround is to use the json format. Please see the examples below.

```
aws emr create-cluster --steps file://./mysteps.json --ami-version 3.1.0 --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m3.xlarge InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m3.xlarge --auto-terminate --log-uri s3://betaestimationtest/logs
```

mysteps.json looks like:

```
[
    {
    "Name": "Intra country development",
    "Type": "STREAMING",
    "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
    "Args": [
        "-files",
        "s3://betaestimationtest/mapper.py,s3://betaestimationtest/reducer.py",
        "-mapper",
        "mapper.py",
        "-reducer",
        "reducer.py",
        "-input",
        " s3://betaestimationtest/output_0_inte",
        "-output",
        " s3://betaestimationtest/output_1_intra"
    ]}
]
```

You can also find examples here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/awscli/examples/emr/create-cluster-examples.rst. See example 13.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying -files twice, you only need to specify once. I forget if the CLI needs the separator to be a space or a comma for multiple values, but you can try that out.

You should replace:

```
Args=[-files,s3://betaestimationtest/mapper.py,-files,s3://betaestimationtest/reducer.py,-mapper,mapper.py,-reducer,reducer.py,-input,s3://betaestimationtest/output_0_inter,-output,s3://betaestimationtest/output_1_intra]
```

with:

```
Args=[-files,s3://betaestimationtest/mapper.py s3://betaestimationtest/reducer.py,-mapper,mapper.py,-reducer,reducer.py,-input,s3://betaestimationtest/output_0_inter,-output,s3://betaestimationtest/output_1_intra]
```

or if that fails, with:

```
Args=[-files,s3://betaestimationtest/mapper.py,s3://betaestimationtest/reducer.py,-mapper,mapper.py,-reducer,reducer.py,-input,s3://betaestimationtest/output_0_inter,-output,s3://betaestimationtest/output_1_intra]
```

Comment: I actually already tried both of these options. The first thing you suggest results in the following error in my console:

`Key value pairs, where values are separated by commas, and multiple pairs are separated by spaces.`

The second option also doesnt work in Amazon, and gives the following error:

`Found 1 unexpected arguments on the command line [s3://betaestimationtest/intraCountryReducer.py]`

Answer (score -1):

Add an escape for comma separating files:

```
    Args=[-files,s3://betaestimationtest/mapper.py\\,s3://betaestimationtest/reducer.py,-mapper,mapper.py,-reducer,reducer.py,-input,s3://betaestimationtest/output_0_inter,-output,s3://betaestimationtest/output_1_intra]
```

Comment: That didn't work. I got this error:

Found 1 unexpected arguments on the command line [s3://str-emr/reduce.rb]
Try -help for more information
Streaming Command Failed!
Command exiting with ret '1'