# Pass comma separated argument to spark jar in AWS EMR using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I am using aws cli to create EMR cluster and adding a step. My create cluster command looks like :

> aws emr create-cluster --release-label emr-5.0.0 --applications Name=Spark --ec2-attributes KeyName=*****,SubnetId=subnet-**** --use-default-roles --bootstrap-action Path=$S3_BOOTSTRAP_PATH --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m4.large InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=$instanceCount,InstanceType=m4.4xlarge --steps Type=Spark,Name="My Application",ActionOnFailure=TERMINATE_CLUSTER,Args=[--master,yarn,--deploy-mode,client,$JAR,$inputLoc,$outputLoc] --auto-terminate

$JAR - is my spark jar which takes two params input and output

$input is basically a comma separated list of input files like s3://myBucket/input1.txt,s3://myBucket/input2.txt

However, aws cli command treats comma separated values as separate arguments and hence my second parameter is being treated as second parameter and hence the $output here becomes s3://myBucket/input2.txt

Is there any way to escape comma and treat this whole argument as single value in CLI command so that spark can handle reading multiple files as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is no possible way of escaping comma from input files.

After trying quite a few ways, I finally had to put a hack by passing a delimiter for separating input files and handling the same in code. In my case,I added % as my delimiter and in Driver code, I am doing

```
if (inputLoc.contains("%")) {
  inputLoc = inputLoc.replaceAll("%", ",");
}
```

Comment: Workaround is to use JSON or YAML step configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27430282/3065307